# Inlcude in email template bank details when user choose "Bank transfer" payment method

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, payment-methods

In my store there are two payment methods enabled. One of these is the "Bank Transfer". I would like to be able to add the bank details in the "New order email template" only when the customer has choosen the "Bank Transfer" payment method.

Is there a way to check this information inside the template with something like

```
{{if payment == 'banktransfer'}}
 Bank Details
....
....
{{endif}}
```

or is there a way to use multiple template based on the payment method specified by the customer?

Comment: I have found a very good blog post which helped me to solve that:<br/>
[Magento sales e-mail payment block (from Jeffrey de Graaf)](http://jeffreydegraaf.nl/2014/01/26/magento-sales-e-mail-payment-block/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to do it by including a block into the template.
In the middle of my template I inserted this:

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/order/bankdetails.phtml' order=$order store=$store}}
```

insid the bankdetails.phtml file I perform this check to decide whether to include bank details or not:

```
<?php $_order = $this->getOrder(); ?>
<?php if(!is_null($_order) && $_order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode() == 'banktransfer') : ?>

....
bank details
....

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you. In my solution:

I have two payment methods: 'banktransfer' and 'cashondelivery'. These are the codes of the methods.
In email template files getting payment method code you have to insert this:

```
{{var order.getPayment().getMethodInstance().getCode()}}
```

In my order_new.html template file the block of the "Bank Details" was:

```
<table>
  ...
</table>
```

I inserted a class attribute into table element:

```
<table class="{{var order.getPayment().getMethodInstance().getCode()}}-email">
  ...
</table>
```

My template file uses inline CSS file (at the begining):

```
{{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}
```

In this email skin/frontend/base/default/css/email-inline.css I inserted this:

```
.cashondelivery-email
{
   display: none;
}
```

It results if the code of the payment method is 'cashondelivery', the block of the "Bank Details" won't be displayed.

If later there will be more (not banktransfer-like) method, I will only add some class selectors to CSS file.

If in your shop 'Guest Checkout' is allowed, it is worth repeatig the above changes in order_guest_new.html template files.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to leave this answer here for Magento 2...

I have set up a custom module which includes the ability to add bank details to the email. There are many resources online which detail how to set up a custom module so I am just going to add the specific files related to the question here:

In the email template add the following:

```
{{layout area="frontend" handle="banktransfer_email_template_message" order=$order }}
```

Then in your module add the following file:

app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/banktransfer_email_template_message.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"
  label="Bank Transfer Email Template Message"
  design_abstraction="custom">
<body>
    <block class="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\View"
           name="vendor.modulename.email.template.message"
           template="Vendor_ModuleName::email/banktransfer/message.phtml">
    </block>
</body>
```

Then add the View class:

app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Block/View.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

class View extends Template
{
    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     * */
    private $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $data
        );
        $this->scopeConfig = $context->getScopeConfig();
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAdditionalInfoMessageFromConfig() {
    /** I have added a custom field to admin where I retrieve the 
    * bank details but you can enter your bank details in the text 
    * field already given in 
    * Stores/Configuration/Sales/Payment Methods/Bank Transfer/Instructions text field */
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('payment/banktransfer/instructions', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    }

}
```

Add the template file:

app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/email/banktransfer/message.phtml

```
<?php
/** @var \Vendor\ModuleName\Block\View $block */
?>
<div class="bank-transfer-email-message">

    <?php
    $var = $block->getData('order')->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();

    if ($var == 'banktransfer') {
        echo $block->getAdditionalInfoMessageFromConfig();
    }
    ?>

</div>
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!